# Hashing uncertain objects

Tags: python, hash

I need to design object that support some sort of uncertainty (or wild characters, if you wish) it its components. 
The work is done in Python.

Consider the following class

```
class C():
    def __init__(self, p1):
        self.p1 = p1
```

The property `p1` can be either "x", "y", "z", but sometimes "x or y", or any other combination.

It is required that if `p1` of `c1` is 'x' and `p1` of `c2` is 'x or y', then `c1 == c2` will return `True`. This is easily achieved by supplying a proper `__eq__` function. 
However, these objects need also to be stored in sets, therefore I need to supply a `__hash__` function. 
How would you calculate hash function for this case, such if `c1 == c2` then `hash(c1) == hash(c2)`?

## Option 1: hashing the property

**Not good** Here's why

```
c1 = C('x')
c2  = C('x or y or z')
c1 == c2 #True
hash(c1) == hash(c2)#False
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't fully read your question (and `Option 1` should've really been a comment to my answer). Updated my answer.

Comment: I think you shouldn't use equality for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equality criterion is not transitive, and therefore invalid:

```
C('x') == C('x or y') == C('y')
```

but

```
C('x') != C('y')
```

Since you can construct an element that equals all others `C('x or y or z or a or ...')`, the only hash function that fulfills c1 == c2 ⇒ hash(c1) == hash(c2) is a constant one, i.e.

```
def __hash__(self):
    return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just realized that my design requirement is faulty. The requirement that C('x') == C('x or y') is True and that C('y') == C('x or y') is True will also require that
C('x') == C('y') will also be True. Looks that I need to re-think my design and maybe give up the ability to have object hashes. What do you think?

Comment: I think this should've been a comment or an addition to the original question ;) .

Answer (score 0):

> It is required that if `p1` of `c1` is 'x' and `p1` of `c2` is 'x or y', then `c1 == c2` will return `True`.

That's very sketchy (i.e. probably bad) design. Equality is supposed to be transitive, so that if `c1 == c2` and `c2 == c3`, then `c1 == c3`. Now, your specification requires that `C('x') == C('x or y')` and `C('x or y') == C('y')`, which should imply that `C('x') == C('y')` - but you probably don't want that to be true. (And I see that you figured that out while I was writing this.)

What I would suggest is that you leave `__eq__` alone and use a completely different method to perform these "fuzzy" comparisons, perhaps something like `is_compatible_with`. Or if you are going to reimplement `__eq__`, at least make it something sensible that obeys the transitive property, such as just comparing the string arguments. That may mean that `__eq__` isn't very useful for your particular application, but that's okay; that's why you can create other methods.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to make all your objects return the same hash. This degrades the set O(1) performance to O(n) as the contained objects will all be inserted into the same slot. The discrimination will then be done using the `__eq__` method.

Regarding your requirements, David has already replied extensively.